# Reading Caffe vector extracted features, reshape vector in python

Tags: python, arrays, vector, caffe

I've used the tutorial of [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/feature_extraction.html) to extract successfully features from a set of images. Then, I used this code to convert the results stored in features file under leveldb format to npy file :

```
input_path='../examples/images/'
path='../examples/test/npy/'
files = os.listdir(input_path)

db = leveldb.LevelDB('../examples/_temp/features')

for k in range(len(files)): 
        datum = caffe_pb2.Datum.FromString(db.Get(str(k)))
        arr = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)
        file=files[k]
       out=np.save(path+file[0:len(file)-4],arr)
```

However, the result of extraction from each image is represented by vector arr must be 4096-dim vector, which is not my case as shown below

```
>>> arr
array([[[ 0.    ],
        [ 0.    ],
        [ 0.    ],
        ...,
        [ 0.    ],
        [ 0.    ],
        [ 0.199 ]]])
>>> arr.shape
(1, 4096, 1)
```

I'm not familiar with python. I need to save this array as 4096-dim in npy file, in order to further store it in csv file as one line that will be read by matlab.
How to convert the vector `arr` to 4096-dim?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: please do not post screen shots, but rather cut-paste the text itself. search engines cannot index the information from the screen shot.

Comment: Okay @Shai,  sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `shape` of `arr` to be 4096 dim, instead of `(1, 4096, 1)`?
In that case, you might want to use [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
arr.flatten()
```

To convert `arr` to 1D.

Comment: Yes, this is it. I store it in csv file and it gives the right output. Thank you very much